# Create and download a CSV file from a Flask view

Tags: python, csv, flask

I am trying to allow the user to download a CSV file with data defined by their actions. The file doesn't exist, it's created dynamically. How can I do this in Flask?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Generate the data with [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) and [stream the response](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/streaming/). Use [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) to write to an in-memory buffer rather than generating an intermediate file.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from io import StringIO
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.wrappers import Response

app = Flask(__name__)

# example data, this could come from wherever you are storing logs
log = [
    ('login', datetime(2015, 1, 10, 5, 30)),
    ('deposit', datetime(2015, 1, 10, 5, 35)),
    ('order', datetime(2015, 1, 10, 5, 50)),
    ('withdraw', datetime(2015, 1, 10, 6, 10)),
    ('logout', datetime(2015, 1, 10, 6, 15))
]

@app.route('/')
def download_log():
    def generate():
        data = StringIO()
        w = csv.writer(data)

        # write header
        w.writerow(('action', 'timestamp'))
        yield data.getvalue()
        data.seek(0)
        data.truncate(0)

        # write each log item
        for item in log:
            w.writerow((
                item[0],
                item[1].isoformat()  # format datetime as string
            ))
            yield data.getvalue()
            data.seek(0)
            data.truncate(0)

    # stream the response as the data is generated
    response = Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv')
    # add a filename
    response.headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename="log.csv")
    return response
```

If the `generate` function will need information from the current `request`, it should be decorated with `stream_with_context`, otherwise you will get a "working outside request context" error. Everything else remains the same.

```
from flask import stream_with context

@stream_with_context
def generate():
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Flask-Excel](https://flask.pyexcel.org/) library uses PyExcel to generate a CSV or other spreadsheet format and produces a Flask response. The docs list how to produce other formats and the full API for what data can be used.

```
pip install flask-excel
```

```py
import flask_excel as excel

@app.route('/download', methods=['GET'])
def download_data():
    sample_data=[0, 1, 2]
    excel.init_excel(app)
    extension_type = "csv"
    filename = "test123" + "." extension_type
    d = {'colName': sample_data}
    return excel.make_response_from_dict(d, file_type=extension_type, file_name=filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# imports
import os
from flask import Flask, abort, send_file
from Sisdoc import Sisdoc
import socket
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

PATH = os.path.commonpath([os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/..'])
FILE= os.path.join(PATH, 'sisdoc.csv')

@app.get('/')
def sisdoc():
    sisdoc = Sisdoc()
    data = sisdoc.get_sisdoc() # Put your data here
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.columns = ['sisdoc', 'data', 'hora', 'tipo', 'status', 'descricao'] # Put your columns name here
    df.to_csv('sisdoc.csv', sep=';', index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
    try:
  
        return send_file(FILE, as_attachment=True)
        
    except FileNotFoundError:
        abort(404)

 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```