# Proper rendering of Flask produced CSV files in Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, flask

Here is a minimal example of a flask view, which produces a CSV (python 2.7).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
import StringIO

from flask import Flask, Response

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/example.csv')
def example_csv():
    f = StringIO.StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Header 3'])
    writer.writerows([unicode(_).encode('utf-8') for _ in row] for row in (['1', '2', '3'], 
                                                                           ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                                                                           [u'£', u'€', u'¥']))
    response = Response(f.getvalue(), mimetype='text/csv')
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = u'attachment; filename=example.csv'
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True)
```

Opening in Excel gives:

```
Header 1    Header 2    Header 3
1   2   3
a   b   c
Â£  â‚¬ Â¥
```

With Apple's Numbers App, the last line renders properly. How can I get Excel to render properly? Am I missing some sort of encoding setting?

Comment: Looking at the headers coming back when you request this endpoint, is the `Content-Type` set to `text/csv; charset=utf-8`?

Comment: Yes,

➜  ~ curl -v http://127.0.0.1:5000/example.csv
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /example.csv HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 53
< Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.csv
< Server: Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.9
< Date: Wed, 04 May 2016 08:21:54 GMT
<
Header 1,Header 2,Header 3
1,2,3
a,b,c
£,€,¥
* Closing connection 0

Answer (score 5):

[Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6002256/135978) suggests that the issue is that Excel does not consider the file to be UTF-8 unless it starts with a Byte Order Mark (for reasons of backwards compatibility with its previous behavior).

Try adding an encoded BOM as the first three bytes of your response:

```
response = Response(u'\uFEFF'.encode('utf-8') + f.getvalue(), mimetype='text/csv')
```

Alternatively, the first answer suggests that if that doesn't work, shipping the contents as UTF-**16** will *often* work (but not for every version of Excel, even then).

Comment: *Laughs* Good catch!  Fixed.

Comment: The BOM added gives:

ï»¿Header 1 Header 2 Header 3
1 2 3
a b c
Â£ â‚¬ Â¥

How would sending as utf-16 be done?

Comment: Just add a `charset='utf-16'` keyword argument to your `Response` call and change `encode('utf-8')` to `encode('utf-16')`

Comment: Response doesn't take a charset argument. Changing encode() to utf-16 gives:

Header 1 Header 2 Header 3
ÿþ1 ÿþ2 ÿþ3
ÿþa ÿþb ÿþc
ÿþ£ ÿþ& ÿþ¥

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of python3, create StringIO, write `\uFEFF` and then create csv writer to render correctly in Excel 2019.

This method also solves the problem of the Chinese not being rendered correctly.

flask version=2.0.1

```
    import csv
    from io import StringIO
    
    from flask import Flask, Response
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    
    @app.route('/example.csv')
    def example_csv():
        def generate():
            f = StringIO()
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(u'\uFEFF')
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(('Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Header 3'))
            dataset = [['1', '2', '3'],
                       ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                       ['£', '€', '¥'],
                       ['壹', '貳', '參']]
            for row in dataset:
                writer.writerow(tuple(row))
                yield f.getvalue()
                f.seek(0)
                f.truncate(0)
    
        response = Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv')
        response.headers.set("Content-Disposition",
                             "attachment",
                             filename='example.csv')
        return response
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

[Excel render thumbnail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leoL9.png)

References:

[Create and download a CSV file from a Flask view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011341/create-and-download-a-csv-file-from-a-flask-view)

[Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```py
import codecs
from flask import make_response

output = make_response(
    codecs.BOM_UTF8.decode("utf8") + codecs.BOM_UTF8.decode() + f.getvalue())
output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
return output
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use utf-8 with signature, so replacing "utf-8" with "utf-8-sig" should work.

In your code: unicode(_).encode('utf-8-sig')